# Recursive Equation : $X_t=-\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\phi^{-j}W_{t+j}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

$X_t=\phi X_{t-1}+W_t$

$\Rightarrow X_{t-1}=\frac{1}{\phi} X_{t}-\frac{1}{\phi}W_t$

Where , $|\phi|>1$ .

But how does the following recursion relation occur : $$X_t=-\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\phi^{-j}W_{t+j}$$ ?

I tried to do this by Again writing :

$X_{t-1}=\frac{1}{\phi} X_{t}-\frac{1}{\phi}W_t$

$\Rightarrow\phi X_{t-2}+W_{t-1}=\frac{1}{\phi} X_{t}-\frac{1}{\phi}W_t$

$\Rightarrow\phi [\frac{1}{\phi} X_{t-1}-\frac{1}{\phi}W_{t-1}]+W_{t-1}=\frac{1}{\phi} X_{t}-\frac{1}{\phi}W_t$

But it seems i have gone to the same equation .

Comment: I guess the general term exists only if $\left|\phi\right| < 1$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong No, $|\phi|>1$ . Please , see my edit .

Comment: Yes, I actually mean that... sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, $X_t=\phi X_{t-1}+W_t$, suggesting $X_t=\frac1\phi(X_{t+1}-W_{t+1})=-\phi^{-1}W_{t+1}+\phi^{-1} X_{t+1}$. Substituting this recursively, it follows that $$\begin{align*}X_t&=-\phi^{-1}W_{t+1}+\phi^{-1}(-\phi^{-1}W_{t+2}+\phi^{-1}X_{t+2})\\&=-\phi^{-1}W_{t+1}-\phi^{-2}W_{t+2}+\phi^{-2}X_{t+2}\\&=\dots\\&=-\phi^{-1}W_{t+1}-\phi^{-2}W_{t+2}-\phi^{-3}W_{t+3}+\dots\\&=-\sum_{j=1}^\infty \phi^{-j}W_{t+j}\end{align*}$$i.e. as an expansion in terms of $\phi^{-1}$ with coefficients $-W_{t+j}$. This converges if $W_{t+j}$ grows slow enough, i.e. $W_{t+j}\in O(r^j)$ such that $|r/\phi|<1$.

---

Is this meant as a stochastic difference equation? $W_t$ a Wiener process?

Comment: Yes , you're right . This is a stochastic equation . And the model $X_t=\phi X_{t-1}+W_t$ is an AR(1) model where $W_t$ is *White Noise*.

Comment: ah, oops -- I know I had seen something like this before but I've been reading about SDEs where $W_t$ represents a continuous-time Wiener process and forgot that it denotes white noise in autoregression models